# Pivot Point Equations

Tags: mechanical-engineering, measurements

Assume we have a platform fixed to a pivot point:

[image: Forgive the crude image]

We use 2 rods, either side of the pivot point, but at different distances from it.

If we were to lift ROD 1 by a certain amount, how much would ROD 2 have to lower?

What other information is needed in solving this problem?

Comment: This reads like a homework problem.  If it is, please provide the work you've done already to solve it, according to Engineering.SE's [stance on homework questions](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121/what-should-our-position-be-on-homework-type-questions).

Comment: @grfrazee, this is not a homework problem. I'm a CS student with a curiosity for engineering :)

Comment: It would still be good to [show your work](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335/the-engineering-se-policy-on-check-my-work-questions).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be simply understood via [similar triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)). When you raise one rod, it creates a triangle between its original point (where it connects with the platform), its final position and the fulcrum. The other rod creates a *similar triangle*. You can therefore find the relation between how much each rod moves via the difference in scale of the triangles.

If one triangle is $X$ times larger than the other, then that triangle will also move $X$ times more than the other.

Since it's almost trivial with a casual glance at the link above, I'll leave it to you to find the difference in scale of the triangles.